# replace value if exist in a column of csv file

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

I need to find the all value the first three parts of an ip and if it repeats, I change the fourth part to .255 .

Example :

```
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.209
216.239.35.209
209.85.255.97
209.85.255.97
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.209
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.209
```

becomes

```
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
209.85.255.97
209.85.255.97
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
```

Thanks

Comment: why doesn't this ip `209.85.255.97` been modified?

Comment: because this ip does not have the same three prefix as the other two ip

Comment: 216.239.35.* and the other ip  209.85.255.*

Comment: *as the other two ip*  - what *two ip*? preceding? following?  you did not mention that in your question. That's not obvious. If you implied something - that doesn't mean everybody can recognize that

Comment: the idea is to eliminate the fourth part of all the ips and see if there is redundancy if we change all the ip by adding .255 instead of the fourth one.   But I'm stuck I could not do it

Comment: Start with a beginners guide to `awk` please and post some *code* too.

Comment: Based on the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239770/6136214), it seems his code looks for *blocks* of repeats of the first three fields. If there's only one block, leave it alone, if there are at least two blocks, (*i.e.* the three fields of one of the blocks is a duplicate of those of another block), change those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this shell script resolves the problem:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat tt4 | sort -u | cut -d. -f1,2,3 > tmp1
awk 'BEGIN {while ((getline < "tmp1") > 0) { a[$0]++; if(a[$0] == 2) print; 
if (a[$0] >= 2) print }}' | sort -u > tmp2


while read line
 do 
 a=`echo $line |  cut -d. -f1,2,3`

   if [ `cat tmp2 | grep $a` ]; then

    fin=.255

    b=`echo $a$fin`
    echo $b

   else

   echo $line
   fi

 done < tt4
```

the result is

```
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
209.85.255.97
209.85.255.97
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.36.255
216.239.36.255
```

Comment: Please clarify, if *tt4* contains no lines starting with *209.*, (*i.e.* the output of `grep -v '^209.' tt4`), should the 4th field still be changed?

Comment: whatever the value it must start with the script checks if the first 3 values so exists and repeats it changes the fourth to 255 I tested for several example and it works well

Comment: It's sounds as though you're saying it's looking for **three** or more duplicates -- in *any* order.   Please clarify, if *tt4* contains **three** lines starting with the output of `grep -v '^209' tt4`, should the lines beginning with *209*  have their 4th field changed?

Comment: no, it's only for the first three parts of the chain in this case the "209." will be changed if the fourth part that is ".97" is changed

Comment: Thanks, now suppose the lines beginning with `209.` were `209.85.255.97` and `209.85.255.98` -- should the 4th field of *those* be changed to `255`?

Answer (score 1):

Revised answer based on the [*OP*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239770/6136214), it seems his code looks for *blocks* of repeats of the first three fields.  If there's only *one* block, leave it alone, if there are at least *two* blocks,  (*i.e.* the three fields of one block duplicates those of another block), change the *4th* field of those lines.

Use piped utils to finds blocks with duplicate fields *1-3*, then with a **2nd** `uniq` find only duplicate blocks, (the ones to change), then use those to generate a little `sed` code to do the work:

```
cut -d. -f1,2,3 data | uniq -d | sort | uniq -d | 
sed 's#.*#/^&./s/.*/&.255/#' | sed -f - data
```

Output:

```
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
209.85.255.97
209.85.255.97
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
```

---

This answer avoids:

- temporary files.
- magic numbers (*i.e.* it doesn't check if field #3 or #4 equals *97* or *255*, or something like that).
- shell variables.

Comment: thanks for your answer but the goal is to leave ip with 209 unchangeable

Answer (score 0):

As your educated guess said, `awk` is your friend. But to be honest, your question is excruciatingly terse. You could do something in similar lines as coded below. Please feel free to modify.

```
# awk -v FS='.' -v OFS='.' 'BEGIN{i=1}NR==FNR{rec[i]=$0;$4="";pref[i++]=$0;next}
     END{
       pref[0]=pref[1];pref[i]=pref[i-1]
       for(i=1;i<=NR;i++){
         if(match(pref[i-1],pref[i+1]))
           sub(/.[0-9]+$/,".255",rec[i]);
         print rec[i];

       }
     }' case_file_48238278
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.209
209.85.255.97
209.85.255.97
216.239.35.207
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
216.239.35.255
```

Comment: with this code it gives the change  only in the last line

Comment: @MohamedRachedBenCheikh I doubt that.. You can already see the output below

Comment: I just retest it, it does not work

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'N;s/(.*\.).*\n\1.*/\1255\n\1255/;P;D' file
```

Changes consecutive similar ip addresses to one ending in `255`

```
sed 's/216\.239\.35\..*/&255/' file
```

Changes ip's of a specific kind to ones ending in `255`